# How to build Help based on Markdown in Ruby on Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown

I am willing to create Help manual pages using Markdown files within my Rails application. I am already using Markdown for limited elements in some pages, but I now want to create dynamic pages using MD files. Searching around, I found some tips, but no complete HowTo.

My main issue was generating the route to various pages based on the requested MarkDown file. I propose the solution below, which fits well for documenting my application, and also allows contributors to easily enrich or translate the documentation.

Comment: Considering that markdown does not have any dynamic content, you may want to consider another approach where the markdown is compiled into html and served a static web server. That would be more performant. I understand though that performance may not matter to you for a small documentation site and you just would like to use RoR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing this question, I found the solution.
Here is what I did:

**1** - I created a hierarchy of folders in *public* for supporting several languages. Each folder contains a help_index.md file, which contains links to other MD files:

> - public
>
>   - help-en
>       help-index.md
>       logging.md
>       user-ceation.md
>   - help-fr
>       help-index.md
>       logging.md
>       etc.

**2** - I created a route (routes.rb) to reach these pages based on the page name:

```
#  get '/help',
get 'help/*page_name', :controller => 'help', :action => 'help', :as => :help
```

**3** - I created a link from the application header (application.html.erb):

```
<%= link_to t('Help'), help_path("help_index") %>
```

**4** - I created a template for the help pages:

```
<% provide(:title, t('Help')) %>
<h1>Help pages</h1>
<p>
<%= displayHelp %>
</p>
```

**5** - I created a controller (help_controller.rb) for displaying the page:

```
class HelpController < ApplicationController

  def help
  end
end
```

**6** - I created a helper (application_helper.rb) for interpreting Markdown based on Redcarpet gem:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def markdown
        markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, :autolink => true, :space_after_headers => true)
  end

  def displayHelp
    filename = File.join(Rails.root, 'public', "help-#{I18n.locale.to_s}", "#{params[:page_name]}.md")
    begin
      file = File.open(filename, "rb")
      markdown.render(file.read).html_safe
    rescue Errno::ENOENT
      render :file => "public/404.html", :status => 404
    end
  end
end
```

And it works fine!